# Should we remove empty hyperlinks?

Tags: discussion, bug

This is generally how a hyperlink looks like:

```
[enter link description here][1]
```

But what if I do it like this?

```
[][1]
```

**This will not be rendered** and can lead to some phishing links or some serious threats! So I suggest removing such or banning such links. Maybe a script can be written to ban empty hyperlinks which are actually in the post (non-clickable), but viewable on edit mode.

> You can view a live example by clicking the edit option.

Comment: *"This [...] can lead to some phishing links or some serious threats!"* ... it can? How?

Comment: These hyperlinks can actually be viewed when you click edit !

Comment: @Tom not `phishing` but at least some you can say suspicious hidden things

Comment: @Tom maybe Imagine some secret agent hiding such things in their post

Comment: suspicious links are detected by the Smoke Detector but I'm not sure if this specific one is caught

Comment: @rene exactly! I don't understand why people are downvoting :( , it's my first time on meta.

Comment: Guys can I know the reason why I am being downvoted ? Is it a bad question or a duplicate?

Comment: I don't think anyone considers this to be problem. That matches "not useful" which explains the downvotes.

Comment: @rene so like I need to come up with a reason `how it can be harmful` right?

Comment: *"So I suggest removing such or banning such links. Maybe a script can be written to ban empty hyperlinks which are actually in the post (non-clickable) but viewable on edit mode."* but..... why? I mean they're not doing any harm, just edit them out if you naturally come across them

Comment: HTML comments can also be used to “hide” things in posts. Should we ban those as well?

Comment: Lol i was so excited that I found a bug , stupid me :(

Comment: @yivi  saw that edit haha!

Comment: @yivi Can you please stop destroying the post? :p

Comment: Should I delete it guys?

Comment: You can't delete the question, now that it's been accepted and upvoted.

Comment: @nick you’ll probably find it hard to believe, but the “destruction” was not intentional. Sorry about that. Many thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Lol my meta carrer ends here, I am back to SO now

Comment: @yivi Looks like most of the issues were caused by automatic conversion of hyphens to em-dashes, maybe a system setting somewhere that you wanna disable ^^

Comment: @cigien I did undo, like if it would be useful for future , then I can keep it or else on your suggestions I'll delete

Comment: *"Lol my meta carrer ends here"* No it doesn't. You found something weird and reported it. Several community members don't see it as an issue, hence the downvotes (mind that these don't necessarily mean the question itself is bad), so this is all fine and the usual process. This is how it works and you did nothing wrong.

Comment: It's up to you, but don't feel any pressure to delete it. The question is on-topic, and perfectly fine, if uninteresting to some users.

Comment: yeah @Tom thanks , I'll keep this question here ! :)

Comment: Yes, please keep it. This can now work as a duplicate target if someone else finds the some issue and reports it.

Comment: @Tom I have one more question , will it in any way affect SEO?

Comment: @cigien same question for you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It requires <s>two</s> three steps to be considered truly *heinous*; you have to click the Edit button, copy the link *and* then follow up with pasting the link in your browser address bar.

I don't disagree that this *could* be a problem but this is no different than if someone hid the same link in an HTML comment.  The only way you're actually exposed to it is if you know to click the edit button.